# How to export data from Cassandra table having JSON value to a CSV file?

Tags: json, cassandra, export

I have a table in Cassandra DB and one of the column has value in JSON format. I am using Datastax DevCenter for querying the DB and when I try to export the result to CSV, JSON value gets broken to separate column wherever there is coma(,). I even tried to export from command prompt without giving and delimiter, that too resulted in broken JSON value.

Is there anyway to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COPY` command to export the table as a whole with a different delimiter.
The option can be added in a `WITH` clause.
For example:

```
COPY keyspace.your_table (your_id,your_col) TO 'your_table.csv' WITH DELIMITER='|' ;
```

Then filter this data programmatically in whatever way you want.